# Nuxt/Vue cannot reload when use multiple iframe in template

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I use Nuxt to setup the Vue app and it have the auto reload feature when I changed something in files.

The problem appears when I have to make a page which has multiple iframes contain other page (.vue) from localhost. However, the auto reload stuck when I do that, even the manual reload from browser is not working. Anyone have idea how to fix this. Thanks a lot.

[image: Image error in dev tools]

**container.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="workplace-container">
    <iframe class="iframe-resizable" scrolling="no" src="example"></iframe>
    <iframe class="iframe-resizable" scrolling="no" src="example"></iframe>
  </div>
</template>


<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  components: {}
})
</script>
```

**example.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="e-container">
    <div>
      <h1 class="title">
        A
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  components: {}
})
```

Both of those files are in same folder "pages"

Comment: Tried a hard refresh (`ctrl + shift + R` while having dev tools open)? Why do you use iframes rather than vanilla components here?

Comment: Thanks for response,  the `ctrl + shift + R` is not working. I use iframe mostly because it has inner screen width/height, I want it to it to remain as 100vh and 100vw

Comment: You should have some errors elsewhere I guess. If you want to to take the whole viewport, just apply CSS to it. Iframes will be a pain to work with, as you can already see. It's purpose is not to fit the whole screen but to integrate windows to other websites (essentially).

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation today where I had multiple iframes on a single page that loaded a Nuxt page and the browser got stuck after the first load. Reload doesn't work. Pressing the `ESC` key and then pressing the `RETURN` key on the address bar would work. I observed that the HTTP request gets stuck in the pending state. I was vaguely aware that browsers (or dev servers, I am unsure at this point) tend to have limited connections to the same domain in certain situations.

As a temporary solution what worked is disabling hot module reload by disabling a network request to `/__webpack_hmr/client` using Chrome DevTools > Network > Right-click the said request and block this specific URL. HMR will not work but you should now be able to reload the page manually without getting stuck now.